# Pipenv throws syntax error for f-strings through pipenv run

Tags: python, pipenv, f-string

I have a strange error with f-strings and pipenv.

I have a flask app that I am launching through pipenv. The code executes perfectly if I enter pipenv shell and launch the app as below:

```
pipenv shell
python app.py
```

Instead, if I launch the app as below:, I get the following error:

```
pipenv run app.py
```

I get the following error:

```
Loading .env environment variables…
File "\app.py", line 43
    logger.info(f'{TRADES_FILE} exists, loading')
                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Using python 3.7.7, I've re-created the virtual environment a few times and forced python 3.7 as well but it doesn't seem to change the above. The issue seems to be around f-strings as, if I remove f-strings, the code executes fine.

I have a batch script using pipenv run so would be good to launch using this method...

Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you try `python -m pipenv run app.py` ?

Comment: Thanks!
Ok, so I've managed to get it to work. Looks like python 2.7 got installed when I installed Node JS (not sure why) and Windows in its wisdom associated py files with 2.7 instead of 3.7. Uninstalled 2.7 and running the command said that there wasn't an associated application with the file. So linking it back to python (c:\windows\py.exe, not the python.exe where it was installed) fixed the problem... I'm going to put this down to some odd Windows quirk...